# Java Lambda - finding if any String element of list matches partially with any element of another list

Tags: java, lambda

I've 2 lists of `String`

```
A = {"apple", "mango", "pineapple", "banana", ... }

B = {"app", "framework",...}
```

What I'm looking for is this: is any element of B at least a partial match ( `substring/contains/startsWith` ) with any element of A. e.g., 1st element of B 'app' matches partially with at least one element 'apple'.

Other closely matching topics on StackOverflow don't consider 2 lists.

Is there any elegant way to express a solution using Java lambda?

I feel it's a general problem in Search domain. So, if there is any helping or interesting read on this topic, I'd be glad to receive pointers.

Comment: the first thing is parallelization. The hits on apple do not depend on the hits on mango. Then some kind of memorization. The hit on apple is good also for pineapple. If this work I will post it as an answer. Before using lambda/streams make the normal loops work. then if the lists are 10k+ long then think about streams and lambdas

Comment: @efekctive: Why? Streams are not just a performance thing, they can make the code easier to understand as well.

Comment: If you solved the problem in the first place. I have plenty of "stream makes life easier, oops, this does not solve the problem

Comment: @efekctive: Why do you think loops are "the first place"?

Comment: The reverse: why do you think they are not? It is a mater how one thinks

Comment: @efekctive: I have to confess that I kind of grew up with procedural programming and got to know functional style only a few years ago. But I found that it has huge advantages. You already mentioned parallelization. There are many others. So today I would no longer recommend to start with procedural style anymore.

Comment: Who is denying the advantages? I do not believe in dogmas or trends. I use anything that makes sense. BTW, parallelization existed before streams. Do not make this something it is not. Logging off

Comment: Actually the memorizing will be hard to make work. Forget about caching the previous hits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by elegant, but try this:

```
List<String> r = list1
  .parallelStream()
  .filter( w1->{
      return list2
        .parallelStream()
        .anyMatch( w2->w1.contains(w2) ); 
      }
   )
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

`anyMatch` (and `filter`) can be short circuited and will abort the stream of the second list after finding the first match of `w1.contains(w2)` and return true if found, giving some efficiency. Use this to filter the first stream. Do it in parallel streams.

Comment: Edited per comments.

Comment: Your code generates a correct list. I was just looking for a boolean value if the condition could be satisfied.
A simple tweak from your solution works:

`boolean anyMatch = listOne.parallelStream()
                                  .anyMatch( w1-> listTwo.parallelStream()
                                                         .anyMatch( w2->w1.contains(w2) ) );
        
      System.out.println(anyMatch);`

Answer (score 2):

You could chain streams of the two `List<String>` and filter  with `String.contains()` or any other condition you want to use (`substring()`, `startsWith()`) .

Then you could map couple of String that valid the condition into a `String` array :

```
List<String> listOne = Arrays.asList("apple", "mango", "pineapple", "framework");
List<String> listTwo = Arrays.asList("app", "frame");

List<String[]> values = listOne.stream()
    .flatMap(x -> listTwo.stream()
        .filter(y -> x.contains(y))
        .map(y -> {
            return new String[] { x, y };
        }))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

for (String[] array : values) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}
```

Output :

> [apple, app]
>
> [pineapple, app]
>
> [framework, frame]

Comment: I was actually looking for a boolean result for partial String match. The 2nd example code which you wrote involves `List.contains` and not `String.contains` and the output is false as I checked.

Comment: Right. I don't compare String in the second one. Sorry, I didn't tested this one. I updated to remove it. Anyway, thank you for the feedback.